# In Cabin in the Woods, why does he start the car with his left hand?

Tags: film-techniques, the-cabin-in-the-woods, editing

*The Cabin in the Woods* takes place (mostly) in America. The 20-something cast is in a big RV that has the driver's seat on the left. The ignition should be to the right of the steering wheel. However, at 10 seconds into the movie trailer, we see Chris Hemsworth turn on the ignition with his left hand.

[image]

Was this just included to make the audience subconsciously feel like something is "off"? Or is there a more mundane explanation, like this shot was flipped in the trailer or it's a special RV with the ignition to the left of the steering wheel?

Here's the trailer. This shot is 10 seconds into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think some older RVs had the ignition key on the left side.  Probably to reduce clutter to the right of the driver, and give space to other controls.

This is from a 1963 RV:

[image: ignition on the left of a stirring wheel]

Comment: Plus, in other shots of the trailer the watch is still on his left hand. Doesn't seem like a reverse shot. Looks to be the ignition *is* on the left.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I saw that too:  before the "turn the key" shot, his hand is on the left. But after the shot his hand is on the right. So I wasn't sure. But I bet it's just an older RV like Jiminion says. Sure looks weird in that shot though.

Comment: @BrettFromLA ... before his right hand is in shot, after his left hand is in shot.  I don't think it looks like they reversed the shot.  It just looks like that vehicle has its ignition key on the left.  I think its a stretch to think its to be subliminal.

Comment: the rv in the movie is a Winnebago chieftain - early 80s (83/84).  based on a few quick Google searches I don't believe those were made with the ignition on the left.

Comment: 1988 Chieftain:

http://www.noblerv.com/console/photos/inventory/large/fa5217b775e8ba9.jpg


http://www.noblerv.com/rv/Winnebago/Class%20A%20Gas/8512/Winnebago_Chieftain_31RT

Comment: @Jiminion Looks like you've confirmed it.

Comment: Update pic. 
http://www.custominstrumentpanels.com/images/winnebago_original.jpg